# Как работает $http в Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Какую роль играет метод then в $http сервисе Angularjs

```
service.get_category().then(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [Правильное использование promise в angular.js](http://habrahabr.ru/post/221111/).

Comment: Спасибо пока еще не знаю что это, но уже хоть знаю куда копать...